# Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

Tags: android, react-native, maven, bintray, jcenter

I am trying to build my react-native project for android and getting the following error on Windows but its working on Mac.

```
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1090 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...
> Task :react-native-get-sms-android:generateDebugRFile FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
128 actionable tasks: 128 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-get-sms-android:generateDebugRFile'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-get-sms-android:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-get-sms-android
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 24s
```

My Environment:

- Windows 10 Home
- React Native v66.4
- NodeJS v12.18.1

Found solutions when googled about this error that bintray was down and its status could be tracked at https://status.bintray.com.

But building the project **works fine on Mac environment**, and at the same time, it is **failing in Windows** with `Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway`. Any clues on this weird behavior?

Comment: your Mac just has it cached

Comment: I posted a similar question. I have seen another similar question. I actually think the bintray server is down that serves the remote dependencies.

Comment: It's because of the Bintray sunset. Please read this Blog `https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/`

Comment: Update: Jcenter will still continue to be read only and it seems it was down but now back up accessible

Comment: I have the same problem since today, do you have a solution ? :( How do I check that it is not a cache problem on my Mac @BooleanCheese ?
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If Osvaldo's solution doesn't work, another one is to update your dependency itself which relies on jcenter in its gradle at the current version.

In this case, it's `react-native-get-sms-android`. Updating it may free it from jcenter.

In my case, it was an old version of `react-native-sqlite-2`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue nad removing `jcenter` and adding `maven` solved my problem:

*The `android/build.gradle` file*:

```
repositories {
  + mavenCentral()
  google()
  - jcenter()
  gradlePluginPortal()
  
}
~ ~ ~
dependencies {
  ~ ~ ~

  + mavenCentral()
  google()
  - jcenter()
  + gradlePluginPortal()
  
  maven { URL 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
}
```

**Hint:** The `+` sign means add this line and the `-` means remove that line.

#### Hot news

Yesterday morning jcener was shutdown by Facebook, so in one of my cases because issue was inside a package in `node_modules` folder, I used the following solution instead of above to permanently remove whatever related to `jcenter`:

*The `android/build.gradle` file of that package in `node_modules` folder*:

```
all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
  if(repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository){
    def url = repo.url.toString()
    if (url.startsWith('https://jcenter.bintray.com/')) {
      remove repo
    }
  }
}
```

To keep this `node_modules` changes in the production environment use `patch-package`.