# Start React Native : Error 502 from maven-metadata.xml

Tags: android, react-native

When I execute `npx react-native run-android` I have a 502 error that does not allow me to start my project.

I have read these recents topics : "[React Native: Android "Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70691547/react-native-android-received-status-code-502-from-server-bad-gateway-from-j)" from JCenter and Bintray being discontinued" et "[Could not HEAD maven-metadata.xml. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70687756/could-not-head-https-jcenter-bintray-com-com-facebook-react-react-native-mave)".

They mention that the breakdown is repaired. It's confirmed on the official website : [Sporadic 502 Bad Gateway, 500 Internal Server Error for maven-metadata.xml resources](https://status.gradle.com/incidents/nv93msj8q658)

Sometimes I read that it can come from my cache. How to check this?

```
    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
    > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
    > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
        Required by:
            project :app
            project :app > project :notifee_react-native
            project :app > project :react-native-async-storage_async-storage
            project :app > project :react-native-community_masked-view
            project :app > project :react-native-firebase_app
            project :app > project :react-native-firebase_crashlytics
            project :app > project :react-native-firebase_messaging
            project :app > project :react-native-picker_picker
            project :app > project :sayem314_react-native-keep-awake
            project :app > project :react-native-background-actions
            project :app > project :react-native-camera
            project :app > project :react-native-fast-image
            project :app > project :react-native-fbsdk-next
            project :app > project :react-native-gesture-handler
            project :app > project :react-native-image-picker
            project :app > project :react-native-pager-view
            project :app > project :react-native-photoeditorsdk
            project :app > project :react-native-pinchable
            project :app > project :react-native-safe-area-context
            project :app > project :react-native-screens
            project :app > project :react-native-svg
            project :app > project :react-native-vector-icons
            project :app > project :react-native-version-check
        > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
                > Could not HEAD 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
    > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:12.+.
        Required by:
            project :app > project :react-native-fbsdk-next
        > Skipped due to earlier error
    > Could not resolve com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0.
        Required by:
            project :app > project :notifee_react-native > com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.13
        > Skipped due to earlier error
```

Comment: Last week there was an outage that was tracked here https://status.gradle.com/ for same incident at the 13th

Comment: incident page https://status.gradle.com/incidents/nv93msj8q658

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

- Go to the android folder.
- Find build.gradle file.
- Change every "jcenter()" into "mavenCentral()".